# Calculate standard error in state space model in R

Tags: r, time-series, bootstrap, state-space-models

I am estimating a DFM in state space form in R. I have used the function spg from the package BB (optim was not working) and dlm to optimize so now I have the parameters of the filter. I now would like to retrieve the standard errors.

I have tried to calculate the Hessian plugging my parameters, but it does not seem to work as Hessian is reported to be negative definite. I have thought of two alternative solutions:

1. Calculate the information matrix as the outer product of the score. But I have encountered the problem that I don't know how to calculate the score; does anyone know if of any function in R that  does this?
2. Do it through bootstrapping, but I don't manage to see how to do it. Do you know of any code I could re-use?

Comment: 1) You may use the package [numDeriv](http://cran.r-project.org/package=numDeriv) to obtain a numerical approximation to the gradient. 2) A non-positive definite Hessian may be a sign that a minimum was not reached.